# Wp Gutenberg Sidebar Edit tooltips/Elements

Tags: wordpress, panel, wordpress-gutenberg

Im looking for help how to remove/change elements in WP Gutenberg editor sidebar. In Past I used `remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv', 'post', 'side' );`  etc. But looks like it is not working anymore.
I'd like to remove unwanted elements like Post Attributes, Categories, Permalink etc stuff.

- [image]

For now I'm hide it with CSS but it is not optimal solution. 
Also I'd like to remove Tags suggestions during publish.
I'd like change post visibility labels.

- [image]
- [image: How do I configure those]

I have found `removeEditorPanel` but are there any docs for that, how to use it, or args? I'm struggling with Gutenberg docs overall, cant find anything helpfully, any info are from gitHub issues or digging inside this thing.
I want some customization to this element :)

Comment: Ok, I have found I can use 
`wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel(...)` to remove side panels. but still that does not solve other issues :)